# Spark SQL encapsulation of data sources

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset where 98% (older than one day ) of its data would be in Parquet file and 2% (the current day - real time feed) of data would be in HBase, i always need to union them to get final data set for that particular table or entity.

So i would like my clients use the data seamlessly like below in any language they use for accessing spark or via spark shell or any BI tools

```
spark.read.format("my.datasource").load("entity1")
```

internally i will read entity1's data from parquet and hbase then union them and return it.

I googled and got few examples on extending DatasourceV2, most of them says you need to develop reader, but here i do not need new reader, but need to make use the existing ones (parquet and HBase).

as i am not introducing any new datasource as such, do i need to create new datasource?  or is there any higher level abstraction/hook available?

Comment: Are you using apache phoenix for hbase ??

Comment: Currently we do not have Phoenix in our Cluster.

Comment: how are you accessing hbase table ?? is it from hive ?? or can you post code if you have any ?

Comment: also you mentioned 2% real time feed , from where this data is reading ? is it from kafka ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a new datasource per se "parquet+hbase", in the implementation you will make use of existing readers of parquet and hbase, may be extending your classes with both of them and union them etc

For your reference here are some links, which can help you implementing new DataSource.

spark "bigquery" datasource implementation

https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

Implementing custom datasource

https://michalsenkyr.github.io/2017/02/spark-sql_datasource

Answer (score -1):

After going through various resource below is what i found and implemented the same.
it might help someone, so adding it as answer

Custom datasource is required only if we introduce a new datasource. For  combining existing datasources we have to extend SparkSession and DataFrameReader. In the extended data frame reader we can invoke spark parquet read method, hbase reader and get the corresponding datasets then combine the datasets and return the combined dataset.

in scala we can use implicits to add custom logic to the spark session and dataframe.

in java we need to extend spark session and dataframe, then when using it use imports of extended classes